# How to make chips unvisible in angular material 15?

Tags: material-ui, angular-material

Migrating to angular material from 14 to 15 cant make chips disappear

In 14 how it should look like:

[image]

In 15

[image]

The class

```
.mat-mdc-standard-chip {
 background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

abling to change color, but not able to remove it completely

Answer (score 0):

this works in my case

```
.mat-mdc-standard-chip {
  background-color: transparent !important;

  .mdc-evolution-chip__action--primary {
    border-width: 0px !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
  }
}
```